# Generating a random number within range of 0-9 in x86 8086 Assembly

Tags: assembly, random, x86, x86-16

First of all, I am very new to 8086 Assembly and it has been pretty difficult for me the grab the knowledge. Nevertheless, I'll do my best.

I have been trying to write a code to generate a random number within range of 0-9. After looking into several examples and suggestion, this is what I ended up with. I did not apply any mathematical function on the retrieved clock count, for simplicity and also I thought it was unnecessary. I ended up with, for some reasons, generating certain number like 6,7 fewer times than numbers such as 1,3 and 9. I believe it is because I'm taking the lower order of the clock ticks, where the values change so rapidly.

My purpose is to simulate a dice roll which later ill change the range of below codes to 1-6.
My question is, Is this adequate enough for my purpose? or is there any better way to do this?

codes:

```
RANDGEN:        ; generate a rand no using the system time
RANDSTART:
   MOV AH, 00h  ; interrupts to get system time        
   INT 1AH      ; CX:DX now hold number of clock ticks since midnight      
                ; lets just take the lower bits of DL for a start..
   MOV BH, 57   ; set limit to 57 (ASCII for 9) 
   MOV AH, DL  
   CMP AH, BH   ; compare with value in  DL,      
   JA RANDSTART ; if more, regenerate. if not, continue... 

   MOV BH, 49   ; set limit to 48 (ASCII FOR 0)
   MOV AH, DL   
   CMP AH, BH   ; compare with value in DL
   JB RANDSTART ; if less, regenerate.   


   ; if not, this is what we need 
   mov ah, 2h   ; call interrupt to display a value in DL
   int 21h    
RET
```

Answer, by @johnfound:

I found his way is simpler, and takes less time to generate the random number. He mentioned that this works only if you need one single random numbers, or the interval between the random numbers includes pauses for human input. If not, the numbers will not be random at all (I believe due to the time seed that we initially take doesn't change). It is fine for my case, since I am simulating a roll dice, and I need the user intervention (another roll) before I will be running the code again.

```
RANDGEN:         ; generate a rand no using the system time
RANDSTART:
   MOV AH, 00h  ; interrupts to get system time        
   INT 1AH      ; CX:DX now hold number of clock ticks since midnight      

   mov  ax, dx
   xor  dx, dx
   mov  cx, 10    
   div  cx       ; here dx contains the remainder of the division - from 0 to 9

   add  dl, '0'  ; to ascii from '0' to '9'
   mov ah, 2h   ; call interrupt to display a value in DL
   int 21h    
RET
```

What he did:
1.We moved value in DX to AX 
2.We cleared DX. 
3.We moved 10 dec to CX. 
4.We divided AX by CX hence we get a remainder within 0-9 Dec which is stored in DX 5.Finally, we added ASCII '0' (dec 48) to DX to get them into ASCII '0' to '9'.

Comment: Do you want the output to be in the range 1-10 (as your title suggests) or 0-255 (as your question suggests: *...generate a random number of one byte*)? And the code looks like it's trying to do a range of `0` to `9` in ASCII.

Comment: yeah, as in the title, 0-9 to be exact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This trick works only if you need one single random numbers, or the interval between the random numbers includes pauses for **human input**. In all other cases, the numbers will not be random at all.

If you need many random numbers, then there are different pseudo-random number algorithms available.

Another note is that there is more easy way to get the number in the needed interval:

```
    mov  ax, dx
    xor  dx, dx
    mov  cx, 10    
    div  cx       ; here dx contains the remainder of the division - from 0 to 9

    add  dl, '0'  ; to ascii from '0' to '9'
```

You can use this method for every random number generator of course.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works flawlessly. It took less time to generate compare to mine too. But i don't completely understand a few things.

1. xor dx, dx - what is the purpose of this?

2. add dl, '0' - How by adding '0' to DL we actually achieving the ASCII value from 0-9?

Comment: We are not adding 0 (zero) to dl, but the ascii code of the character "0" = 30h = 48. This way, the number in DL (from 0 to 9) will be turned to 30h to 39h which are the characters from "0" to "9". something xor something = 0 always.

Comment: i see, so what we did:  1.We moved value in DX to AX 2.We cleared DX. 3.We moved 10 dec to CX. 4.We divided AX by CX hence we get a remainder within 0-9 Dec which is stored in DX 5.Finally, we added ASCII '0' (dec 48) to DX to get them into ASCII '0' to '9'.

Alright, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a smaller opcode, AAM - Ascii Adjust for Multiplication, for this job. How this opcode work:

```
AH := AL / 10
AL := AL mod 10
```

So, it will be this:

```
mov al, dl
aam
add al, '0'
mov dl, al
```

Comment: It's an older question and so most people already know this, but just for the sake of completeness - all BCD instructions, including aam have been removed from the x86-64 instruction set. They are still available if programming in 16 or 32 bit modes, but not in 64 bit.