# Accessing specific element of array of strings, with an integer index

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, emu8086

I want to access to specific element of array using number that generated randomly.

for example,

I want to generate random number 0-9. After number is generated (in this example we assume random number is generated as 4), I want to access array5 and print screen.

How could I success this.

String array initialization code is below

I edited my code as equal size string like below. Each strings have 8 char.

How can I generate random number?

```
org 100h

array0:    db      "abstract", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array1:    db      "academic", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array2:    db      "accurate", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array3:    db      "bacteria", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array4:    db      "attorney", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array5:    db      "equation", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array6:    db      "umbrella", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array7:    db      "overcome", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array8:    db      "universe", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
array9:    db      "analysis", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
```

Comment: If you changed your code to use fixed sizes so you could do `address = array0 + size*idx`, why did you accept the linear-search answer?

Comment: Actually both of them solved my problem. Thank you both.

Comment: ok, but the search way is a lot less efficient, and you'd only write it that way if you *aren't* making all your strings the same length, to make an array of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way to Peter's solution is to **scan for the $**-terminator `random_number` times:

```
     MOV BX,random_number   
     MOV DI,offset array0  ; Beginning of strings. 
     MOV CX,offset arrayEnd; A label below all "arrays".
     SUB CX,DI             ; Let CX=total size of all strings.
     MOV AL,24h            ; '$' which terminates each string.
     CLD                   ; Ascending scan.
Next:REPNE SCASB           ; Search for '$', start at ES:DI.
     DEC BX                ; 
     JNZ Next              ; Repeat random_number times.
     MOV DX,DI             ; DI now points to the desired string.
     MOV AH,9              ; Use DOS function to print it. 
     INT 21h               ; Output $-terminated string at DS:DX.
     RET                   ; Terminate COM program.
    ; Data section follows:
array0:  db "Car", 0Dh, 0Ah, 24h  
 ...
arrayEnd:db 24h             ; End of strings
```

The code is longer and slower, but it saves space in data section, because the strings don't have to be stuffed to unified length.

Comment: Interesting!  That ended up being more compact than I expected, and doesn't even need range-checking because `rep` checks for CX==0 before doing even the first compare and increment.  Of course with a very high BX like 65535 or 0, it could be quite slow.  (Hmm, I think you do need to test bx,bx / jz to skip searching entirely, unless you put a dummy `'$'` before the first real string.  BX = 0 should give you `array0`, not 65536 iterations of banging your head against arrayEnd :P)

Comment: Thanks it works good. well how could I generate random number. 
I'm totally strange to asm I have experience java, C# so asm looks like rocket science to me :)

Comment: @4GDri True randomness is very difficult to obtain. For a toy project I would prefer to get seconds of current time [MOV AH,2Ch; INT 21h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2703.htm), divide them by string-array length (10) and use the remainder as a pseudorandom number 0..9.

Comment: Hi, thanks I used this code from opened topic in here. 

[url]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855817/generating-a-random-number-within-range-of-0-9-in-x86-8086-assembly[/url]

Answer (score 3):

That's not an array; the elements aren't all the same length.

You need to pad out to some fixed max size so you can scale an index like C
`struct {char c[16];} arr[10];`  to make an array of fixed-size string buffers.
Or make a separate array of pointers like `arr: dw array0, array1, ...`

[Initialise array of strings in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251467/initialise-array-of-strings-in-assembly) shows examples of both ways.  For your case, to pad the entries you might use `align 16` before each, which would emit padding bytes at that position until the current address is a multiple of 16.

(Scaling an index by 16 would normally be `shl di, 4` or whatever register, but original 8086 doesn't have immediate shifts.  So `mov cl,4` / `shl di, cl` if you need compatibility with ancient hardware / emulators.)

---

To index what you currently have (a flat concatenation of strings), you'd probably have to linear search for the 4th `24h` byte.  The 5th string starts after that byte.

Also, if you actually put this data right at the top of a file for a `.com` executable (org 100h), the string data will execute as code.  Don't do that; put your data at the end.